# Laptop discharging when an USB C device is plugged in

Tags: windows-10, charging, usb-c

I have an interesting charging issue with a new laptop. When I connect it to an external mouse and monitor with a USB-c hub, it slowly loses charge even with the charger plugged in.

After some testing, I have found that the charger, battery, and everything else works flawlessly without any external devices or when the mouse is plugged into a regular USB port. But as soon as I plug in any USB-c device (I've tried two hubs and one wireless mouse), the laptop starts to lose charge although it is connected to the charger, charging lights are on (both on the charger and on the laptop), and Windows shows that the laptop is charging. It goes from full battery to empty in about four hours. My guess is that the computer somehow thinks that it gets some power from USB-c (which it could, but it does not) and therefore shuts off the regular charger. Any ideas on how to fix it?

In case it matters, it is Windows 10 Home netbook/tablet (Chuwi Ubook Pro).

Comment: If the charger is not connected, but the mouse is plugged in, does the battery discharge in less than four hours?

Comment: I haven't tested this from 100% to 0%, but from shorter tests, it seems that when USB-c device is plugged in, then the battery drains almost at the same rate regardless of whether the charger is in or not. The only difference is that when I unplug the charger, then Windows says that it works on battery and updates the battery status quite continuously, but when the charger is plugged in, Windows says it is charging, but every 15-20 minutes the battery level jumps downwards.

Comment: One more test: Boot in Safe mode and repeat the above, to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Quick question: what should I look for? I booted in Safe mode, but then Windows does not seem to show battery status and whether or not the computer is charging. I guess I can just drain the battery first and then see whether computer keeps working  or not in Safe mode (when charger + usb-c device are plugged in). Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: The idea is to find whether the computer truly recharges in Safe mode. Your test seems fine.